# Adobe Acrobat Action Wizard and Javascript

Tags: javascript, acrobat, inputbox

I'm using the Action Wizard tool in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. I want to use "execute Javascript" to apply a watermark to the center of the PDF page as well as a persons name to the sides and the top. I successfully did this and here is the code.

```
var cMyText = "This PDF has been created for exclusive use for Max Power.";

this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: cMyText,
    nFontSize:9,
    nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.center,
    nVertAlign:app.constants.align.top,
    nVertValue:-10,
    nOpacity: 0.8,
});

this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: cMyText,
    nFontSize: 9,
    nRotation: 90,
    nHorizAlign: app.constants.align.left,
    nHorizValue: 10,
    nVertAlign: app.constants.align.center,
    nOpacity: 0.8,
});

this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: cMyText,
    nFontSize:9,
    nRotation:-90,
    nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.right,
    nHorizValue:-10,
    nVertAlign:app.constants.align.center,
    nOpacity: 0.8,
});

this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: "DRAFT COPY",
    nTextAlign:app.constants.align.center,
    cFont: "Helvetica-Bold",
    nFontSize:80,
    aColor: ["RGB", 0, 0, 1],
    nRotation:45,
    nOpacity: 0.2,
});
```

Now, here's my issue. The line...

"This PDF has been created for exclusive use for Max Power.";

will change each time I run the action. I don't want to risk having the user mess up the JavaScript by editing it directly in the code. I want to have an input box that will prompt the user to edit this line before the action is executed. Is this possible? Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! The below code did the trick!

```
var dialogTitle = "Please Complete";

var string1 = "This PDF has been created for exclusive use for";
var defaultAnswer = "";

var string2 = app.response("Add PDF recipients NAME or COMPANY",
dialogTitle, defaultAnswer);

var string3 = app.response("Add PDF recipients ADDRESS",
dialogTitle, defaultAnswer);

var cMyText = string1 +"\n"+ string2 +" "+ string3;
var string4 = string2 +"\n"+ string3;

this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: cMyText,
    nFontSize:9,
    nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.center,
    nVertAlign:app.constants.align.top,
    nVertValue:-10,
    nOpacity: 0.8,
});

this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: cMyText,
    nFontSize:9,
    nRotation:90,
    nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.left,
    nHorizValue:10,
    nVertAlign:app.constants.align.center,
    nOpacity: 0.8,
});

this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: cMyText,
    nFontSize:9,
    nRotation:-90,
    nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.right,
    nHorizValue:-10,
    nVertAlign:app.constants.align.center,
    nOpacity: 0.8,
});

this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: string4,
    nTextAlign:app.constants.align.center,
    cFont: "Helvetica-Bold",
    nFontSize:36,
    aColor: ["RGB", 0, 0, 1],
    nRotation:45,
    nOpacity: 0.2,
    bOnTop:false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `app.reponse()` in the [reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf).

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
var name = app.alert("Please enter name below:");

if (name != null) {
    var cMyText = "This PDF has been created for exclusive use for " + user + ".";
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could put a folder level Javascript file on each user's machine, with a `getUser()` function that returned their name. Depending on the network environment, this may or may not be an option, but it would enable document level scripts to determine who the user is.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. Please see below for the option I used.